# Manage (CRUD) Windows Services: any API or Win32 wrapper in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, .net-core, windows-services

Does .NET have any API/Namespace for managing Windows Services (with features similar to `services.msc`)? I can use latest .NET Core if possible but I don't mind using .NET Framework if it's required.

If there is not any built-in .NET API, is there already any Win32 API wrapper for .NET? I will start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/) if there is none, is that the good place?

Comment: Can you be looking for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: "allows you to connect to a running or stopped service, manipulate it, or get information about it."

Comment: @OguzOzgul ah yes, somehow my Google skill failed me today. Thank you very much, exactly what I needed.

Comment: LOL. Have a nice day.

Comment: ServiceController is an old thing. With recent .NET Core (3+), there are Worker Services: https://anthonygiretti.com/2020/01/02/building-a-windows-service-with-worker-services-and-net-core-3-1-part-1-introduction/

Comment: Are you sure they are the same thing (sorry I just quick read your link only)? I need to manage _other_ services, not writing my own.

Comment: @OguzOzgul you want to write an answer? Also found the Nuget package if you want to use it for .NET Core app: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/

Comment: Sadly if you use .NET Core, you cannot create new Service as you would need [ServiceInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller?view=netframework-4.8) for that but it's not available on Nuget.

Comment: Dear Luke, no, thanks, I haven't got sufficient expertise on this API. So your app will work on windows I guess, are you going with .Net Core?

Comment: I think I will go by .NET FW since `ServiceInstaller` is not available on .NET Core (without it you won't be able to create new service). Thanks a lot for pointing me to the namespace.